# how to design a vertical carousel sider in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, vertical-scroll

[image]i want to implement vertical carousel slider where all my element will come vertically one after another . I tried different way but couldnt finding any efficiecnt solution.

i tried different widget like tranform,stack pageview to solve this problem but couldnt finding any solution. using pageview and animation i can make vertical scrolable card but the issue is those are coming one after another like a page way but in my required design i have to design as like one card is laid on another one .

Comment: hi may i know how you solve this issue? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am using carousel_slider package, you can give the ratio like :

```
child: CarouselLoading(
              aspecRatioLoading: 1 / 2.5),
```

you can copy of an example in package library , it will provide you a vertical image sliding to left and right automatically.

Edit: top- bottom movement => CarouselOptions( scrollDirection: Axis.vertical

Comment: i used it but cant able to do as like as mine.
if I use aspectRatio then I got gap between two slider but in my image slider should be overlap to each other

Comment: I see , sorry i guess you shoud do with animations . Still  =>CarouselOptions(              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,  i tried it and liked it.